# Criar uma condicional para imprimir na tela a media e o desvio padrão

Tags: r, if

Gostaria de criar uma condicional para média e desvio padrão de um determinado grupo. Normalmente faço isso dividindo em `subsets`, mas como são muitas categorias achei que seria melhor com uma condicional. Montei um código para testar. Ele roda mas não imprime os resultados na tela.

```
if( males[,2]<=22.11 && 18<=males) {
  print(mean(estatura))
  print(mean(CVF))
  print(mean(VEF1))
}
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(males)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(males, 20))`? E diga como são definidos os grupos.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi, você pode fazer um recorte do banco, com as linhas que obedecem a condição e tirar média, desv-pad...

Considere abaixo o `d.orig` os dados originais:

```
condicao <- males[, 2] >= 18 & males[, 2] <= 22.11 
d.cond <- d.orig[condicao, ]
mean(d.cond$estatura)
```

Você pode usar o `dplyr::filter`

```
library(dplyr)
d.cond <- d.orig %>%
  filter(variavel1 >= 18 & variavel2 <= 22.11) %>% 
  summarise(media = mean(variavel3))
```